# Expo not recognized in React Native project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

For some reason, my react native project is unable to find the expo in the node-modules folder. It only works when I make a new app inside the app and then take the node modules folder and put it in the project I am working on then delete the app I created.

I have tried uninstalling NVM, Expo, and Node and then reinstalling all of them. Resetting my bash profile to set a new path for node, the reinstalling there. Deleting the repo and re-pulling from GitHub.

I have tried npm install while in the project directory.

I am totally lost, any guidance would be much appreciated